# Combining a boxplot and a histogram into one plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a boxplot and a histgramm as you can see in the following image.

[boxplot and histogramm combinaion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hwhkl.png)

I have this for the moment:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(10,7)
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.set_title('Heating need [kWh/m^2]')
ax.set_xlabel('Cluster')
ax.set_ylabel('Heating need')

bp1=ax.boxplot([heating0,heating1945,heating1960,heating1970,heating1980,heating1990,heating2000],labels=['<1945', '1945-1959', '1960-1969', '1970-1979', '1980-1989', '1990-1999', '>=2000'],showfliers=False,patch_artist=True)
plt.setp(bp1['boxes'], color='blue')

ax.plot([200,200,220,230,230,170,130,100,30,30],label='underline for swiss energetic index') #underline for the norms
ax.plot([230,230,250,260,260,200,160,130,60,60],label='upperline for swiss energetic index') #upperline for the norms
#plt.yticks([0,200,400,600,800])
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
```

The result is :[image: code result]

and I want to replace the plot line by a histogramm.

Comment: Hi! Please show us what you've already tried :)

Comment: That's very nice and all, but where's your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `plt.bar`

A minimal example:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.boxplot([100,200,300,400,500],1)
data = [200,200]
ax.bar(range(0,len(data)*2,2),data)
```

Comment: Yes ! Exactly what I want ! Thanks a lot